# Nginx configuration file with .netcore website and couchdb reverse proxy on ubuntu 18.04LTS

Tags: nginx, couchdb, nginx-reverse-proxy

I´m trying to configure nginx as reverse proxy for a website that I´m hosting by myself on ubuntu. There is no server_name, because I´m using the VM IP.

What I want is that if I put the IP on the browser, then the website is displayed, and if I put the IP:5984, the couchdb info is displayed

I have tried multiple options, which perfectly works for the .net core website but can not access to couchdb

Here is my configuration

```
server {
 listen 80;
 location /{
 proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }
 location / {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:5984/;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_buffering off;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
}
```

I also have tried this:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 location / {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }
}
server {
 listen 5984;
 location /{
 proxy_pass http://localhost:5984/;
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_buffering off;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: please share the error.log output. What is not working? Are you able to share the curl command for example you have used for testing? Without those information its hard to help. Btw. you can delete the tailing `/` in your proxy_pass `http;//localhost:5984`.

Comment: I have delete the tailing / but can not restart nginx.

Comment: a good approch is to tail the error.log and use `sudo nginx -t` to check the configuration for errors.

Comment: nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf:13

Comment: That means you have a `/` location configured twice within a single server block. This will not work. Check your `default.conf` file and the server block arround line `13`

Comment: I have separated on 2 servers, but this also not works. Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.  What I want is that if I put the IP on the browser, then the website is displayed, and if I put the IP:5984, the couchdb info is displayed

Comment: Ok let me setup this on my instance and update my answer with a working configuraiton.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the configuration you just shared it looks like NGINX is running on the same instance as your couchdb node (single node?). You can NOT use the same port `5984` for nginx and couchdb! this will not work on Ubuntu. If you want the reverse proxy listen on `5984` let couchbd listen on something else e.g `49152`.

A grep of the error.log if using the same port for couchdb and nginx.

```
2021/02/09 14:25:15 [emerg] 78949#78949: bind() to 0.0.0.0:5984 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/02/09 14:25:15 [notice] 78949#78949: try again to bind() after 500ms
2021/02/09 14:25:15 [emerg] 78949#78949: bind() to 0.0.0.0:5984 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/02/09 14:25:15 [notice] 78949#78949: try again to bind() after 500ms
2021/02/09 14:25:15 [emerg] 78949#78949: bind() to 0.0.0.0:5984 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/02/09 14:25:15 [notice] 78949#78949: try again to bind() after 500ms
2021/02/09 14:25:15 [emerg] 78949#78949: bind() to 0.0.0.0:5984 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/02/09 14:25:15 [notice] 78949#78949: try again to bind() after 500ms
2021/02/09 14:25:15 [emerg] 78949#78949: bind() to 0.0.0.0:5984 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/02/09 14:25:15 [notice] 78949#78949: try again to bind() after 500ms
2021/02/09 14:25:15 [emerg] 78949#78949: still could not bind()
```

I am using docker to run couch db on my testserver:

`docker run -p 55984:5984 -d -e COUCHDB_USER=admin -e COUCHDB_PASSWORD=password couchdb`

```
6339f2af29ed   couchdb          "tini -- /docker-ent…"   5 seconds ago   Up 4 seconds   4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:55984->5984/tcp   elegant_archimedes
```

simple curl response directly to the couchdb:

```
$curl localhost:55984 | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   247  100   247    0     0   2440      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2470
{
  "couchdb": "Welcome",
  "version": "3.1.1",
  "git_sha": "ce596c65d",
  "uuid": "317efcb5527237d5c9e974c5d3680ae3",
  "features": [
    "access-ready",
    "partitioned",
    "pluggable-storage-engines",
    "reshard",
    "scheduler"
  ],
  "vendor": {
    "name": "The Apache Software Foundation"
  }
}
```

This is my working NGINX configuration

```
server {
  listen 80;
  # Proxy location to your backend application. Listen on Port 80.
  location / {
    proxy_pass       http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }

}

server {
  listen 5984;
  # CouchDB ProxyLocation. Using InstanceIP with Port `5984`.
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:55984;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Tests:
Reach out to CouchDB via NGINX

```
$curl localhost:5984 | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   247  100   247    0     0   8095      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  8233
{
  "couchdb": "Welcome",
  "version": "3.1.1",
  "git_sha": "ce596c65d",
  "uuid": "875045f1b2314443a21236808b0223cf",
  "features": [
    "access-ready",
    "partitioned",
    "pluggable-storage-engines",
    "reshard",
    "scheduler"
  ],
  "vendor": {
    "name": "The Apache Software Foundation"
  }
}
```

Reach out to Backend App using NGINX

```
$curl localhost

<h1>Wellcome! Please Login!</h1>
<form action="doLogin.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="user" name="user" />
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

So with this config it works. Currently using NGINX 1.19.5 on CentOS7 without SELinux!

Comment: nginx is not running on port 5984

Comment: it is or at least you try to run NGINX on that port. If your listen directive uses 5984 NGINX will listen on this port if it can! http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen in your case its already used by couchdb. Change the port to something else on the nginx site. Whats the output of `nginx -t?`

Comment: nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful . Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.